# Can't I use the if statement with math operations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string.format, f-string

I am writing some code in order to test if a year is a leap year or not.

So I wrote:

```
year = input("please enter a year: ")

if (year % 4) == 0:

    print(f"{year} is a leap year.")

else:

    print(f"{year} is a nonleap year.")
```

And the error reported is:

```
    if (year % 4) == 0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: `year` is a string...

Answer (score 0):

As `year` is a string, `year % 4` tries to run a string formatting operation. Change to

`if (int(year) % 4) == 0:`

Answer (score 0):

to check if it's the leap year you can use

```
import calendar
print calendar.isleap(2019)
```

if you want to keep your way, you need to convert year into int:

```
int(year)
```

Comment: Hardcoding `2019` in the code doesn't help at all, making the `calendar` use effectively a non-sequiteur -- if they tried to keep their existing `year = input("please enter a year: ")` and use `print(calendar.isleap(year))` with the Python version they're already using, they'd have a very similar problem to the existing one.

Comment: Right, I didn't mean to hardcode the date, just wanted to show the usage of calendar